# Is there an alternate to transactions that allow executing multiple concurrent queries to a table & making sure the table is in consistent state?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multithreading

I have an innodb table that I want to perform on some maintenance queries, those queries are going to happen on parallel threads, and they will include (in that order):

Select, update, select, delete, insert.

I want to only allow 1 single parallel thread to have access to that section, so is there something that would allow me to do this?:

```
mutex.block()
select
update
select
delete
insert
mutex.release()
```

This will be in php, and all queries will be executed using php's function `mysqli_query`.

I am hoping for an alternate to transactions, if nothing but transaction can be done here, then be it.

Comment: By default, InnoDB does row-level exclusive locking for individual updates/deletes. If you want to wrap the entire transaction in a lock, then transactions are your best bet.

Comment: It depends on the method of execution, using proper mutex won't work if you have multiple processes responding to threads since the mutex's created by pthreads cannot be shared (for good reason). If you are executing on the command line using pthreads, then say so and I will provide code ...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL features [table locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html) and [locks (a kind of mutex)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock).

PHP supports pretty much all POSIX locking mechanisms, such as [mutexes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mutex.php) and [semaphores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php) (but these are not available by default, see the related "Installing/Configuring" manual chapters).

But really, I see little reason why you would want to implement your own synchronisation mechanism: transactions exist for this purpose precisely, and are likely to be more efficient and reliable than anything home-brewed.

(if performance is your concern, then a database back-end may not be the right choice)